# beginner question about create-react-app: complete HTML/CSS first and then add to app

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am just starting to use create-react-app. Should I create the HTML/CSS before adding to create-react-app components and applying JSX (so that the layout and elements are styled )? I have not learnt inline styling in React yet, trying to get proficient first.

Comment: I think you're better off doing that after creating the CRA.  Seems like an un-needed step.

Comment: Are you talking about [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes i am. Was just wondering what's best practice and the most efficient for create-react-app?

Comment: Well, if you go to the site linked, you'll get to their [Get Started](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started) section which shows running `npx create-react-app my-app` as the first thing done when creating an app. I would think that would be the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, people start with create-react-app or some boiler plate code. You can simply make all those afterwards.